# Testing function that return objects

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-tests

My web app is built around classes that I call widgets. Their goal is to be reusable and modular, to suit different scenarios. For example, I have a widget called `BreadcrumbWidget` which has two functions:

- `addHome()`: adds the "Home" breadcrumb.
- `addBreadcrumb($title, $url = null)`: adds any number of breadcrumbs.

I have this function in a separate class:

```php
public function getBreadcrumbs()
{
    return (new BreadcrumWidget())
        ->addHome()
        ->addBreadcrumb($this->product->name); // The product's name is Foo
}
```

The above function returns a `BreadcrumbWidget` instance on which I can do `->toArray()` and get the output:

```php
[
    'widget_type' => 'breadcrumb',
    'list' => [
        [
            'text' => 'Home',
            'link' => '/some-link',
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'Foo',
            'link' => null,
        ],
    ],
]
```

I'm uncertain on how to best write tests for `getBreadcrumbs()`. I already have a test class for `BreadcrumbWidget` which checks that `addHome` and `addBreadcrumb` work as expected. For `getBreadcrumbs()` I'd need to test that the result contains the `home` and `Foo` breadcrumbs.

One possible approach would be to mock the `BreadcrumbWidget` class and define the following expectancies:

1. `addHome` is called,
2. `addBreadcrumb` is called with the string 'Foo'.

Though this is currently not possible because `BreadcrumbWidget` is instantiated inside the function and presents a hard dependency. I'd probably need to have factories for all my widgets to enable such testing (and in `getBreadcrumbs()`'s case inject the factory into the class where function is defined). Is this a common practice?

Another approach would be to compare the output of `->toArray()` with an expected array.

What would be the better approach or does someone maybe know a better one?

** I'm using Mockery and I know about `overload` ([see](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html)) which can mock hard dependencies, but I'd rather have a solution without it.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth asking yourself how you would test `getBreadcrumbs()` if you knew nothing about it's implementation details.

So, I would be tempted to just compare the output against an expected data structure.

In your implementation, the thing that changes the output is the value of `$this->product->name`. I would want to mock this in some way so it could be controlled from the test.